# Getting JShell UnresolvedReferenceException when trying to use methods from external library in the image created with JLink tool

Tags: java, java-11, jlink, jshell

I created an application using the JShell API and I'm loading some external libraries using the method `addToClasspath`and I'm using JavaFX for the GUI, additionally I'm loading some snippets from external files. This is working fine when using the command `mvn javafx:run`.
But I cannot use the methods from the external libraries when using the image created using the JLink tool `mvn clean javafx:jlink`. I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR JShellExecutor jdk.jshell.UnresolvedReferenceException: Attempt to use definition snippet with unresolved references in MethodSnippet:open/(String)void-
```

Any ideas?